Is $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ dense in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$?
Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the Schwartz space and  $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the space of smoooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, respectively.
It is well-known that both spaces can be given a Frechet topology respectively, as in this M.SE post.
Now, my question is that

Is $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ dense in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with respect to the Frechet topology of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ described in the above link?

I originally thought not, because an element in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can have arbitrary asymptotic behavior at infinity. However, it might be possible to find a sequence of Schwartz functions "approximating" such a function.
Could anyone please clarify for me?
Update) It is indeed a quite simple issue, on which I just got confused myself..

I think yes. If $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $r>0$ is any radius you can find $g \in \cal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $f=g$ on the closed  ball $B(0,r)$ by multiplying $f$ with a $C^\infty$-function $h$ with compact support such that $h=1$ on $B(0,r)$ and $h=0$ outside $B(0,r+1)$.

@Gerd Yes I just thought of the same idea just now. It seems that I had thought in a too much complicated way before..

Yes, even the set of smooth compactly supported functions $C^{\infty}_{c}$ is dense:
Let $\varphi \in C^{\infty}$ be arbitrary and let $(\varphi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of smooth functions such that
$$
\varphi_n(x) := \begin{cases} \varphi(x) & \Vert x \Vert \leq n \\
0 & n+1 \leq \Vert x \Vert
\end{cases}
$$
that is, equal to $\varphi$ on a ball of radius $n$, $0$ outside a ball of radius $n+1$ and smooth everywhere.
Now let $l \geq 0$ and $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ compact be arbitrary and let $n_0$ be large enough such that $K \subseteq B(0,n_0)$. Then
$$
\sup_{x \in K, \vert \alpha \vert \leq l} \vert \partial^{\alpha} \underbrace{(\varphi_n - \varphi)}_{=0, \text{on} B(0,n)} \vert = 0, \quad n \geq n_0 
$$
since $K \subseteq B(0, n_0) \subseteq B(0,n)$. Hence $\Vert \varphi_n - \varphi \Vert_{l, K} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
Indeed, this is the same idea as that of Gerd and yourself.

Thank you for explicit writing down of the ideas!
